# Use of $ in formatted output functions

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

I was going through the man page for the [printf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/) function and I came across a statement which explains about using **$** in the format string (which I actually didn't understand very well). I then tried to look for some examples for this, but I was not able to find good examples which can explain its usage in the function.

Can anyone provide a simple example that can explain the usage of **$** in any formatted output function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motivating case for `$` formats was the fact that sometimes when you're inserting numbers into a translated string, the order of the inserts changes with the language. In order to be able to just use a translated format string without having to be aware of the order of the values, it's necessary that the format string itself mark the insertion order:

```
// Simplified example, with thanks to Google translate for the azerbaijani.

const char* buy_book[NL] = {
  [fmt_en] = "You can buy %d books for %d dollars.\n",
  [fmt_az] = "Siz %2$d dollar %1$d kitab ala bil\u0259rsiniz.\n",
  // ...
};

void bookoffer(enum Lang variant, int books, int dollars) {
  printf(buy_book[variant], books, dollars);
}
```

Occasionally it is useful to repeat formatted value; `$` can save you from having to provide the value twice:

```
printf("The value at offset %1$d (0x%1$X) is %2$d (0x%2$X)\n", addr, value);
```

You can also use `$` values for precisions specified as `*`:

```
printf("The first %1$d characters of the string are '%2$.*1$s'.\n",
       nchar, str);
```

Comment: Thanks! The example explained it pretty nicely.